# Changing Vbe_on in Pspice - Student capture

Tags: bjt, pspice

I want to change the V_BE_on in my BJT model but I couldn't find any explanation on how to achieve this.

I need VBE on of 0.7[V] and the default I think is 0.8[V]
I tried editing the .model --

```
.model Qbreakn NPN (BF = 100 VBE = 0.7)
```

Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no 'VBE' parameter in a SPICE model. This is indirectly controlled via the 'IS' parameter.

Be aware that a BJR doesn't just "turn on" at a single VBE voltage -- it's all gradual even from VBE=0 (with currents in the fA range).